# Connection from many port(in different agents) to one export (in scoreboard)

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a many(port) to one(export) situation with my agents and the scoreboard. My doubt is how will I make sure that only one out of the many ports can write into the export at an instant of time so that I don't get any complications or lost transactions. any help/advice is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Typically you would have an arbiter, deciding which port would write, maybe considering some priorities. And each port would need to support backpressure to stall the masters that would want to write. The arbiter will allow only one writing master to proceed, the others would wait its turn.

Comment: the arbiter is there already in place ? I mean does uvm export/port takes care of this by itself or would I have to code that up? Thanks

Comment: Got it the simulator will take care of this even though its at the same time stamp

Comment: I thought you're building the synthesizable hardware and asking for advices. I've no idea if your project or class library provides the required building blocks. Sorry if I distracted you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "an instant of time"? Do you mean simulator time or multiple processes trying to clobber each other?

Comment: its simulator time.Your answer has precisely cleared my doubt and you were right, we cannot decide on the order,I just checked that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the ports are called 'serially' so you shouldn't have any lost transactions. Whenever the monitor in the agent is ready to broadcast, it'll call the port write function to which the scoreboard is a subscriber.

However, I don't think there's any guarantee in which order the port write functions are called, so you may still have complications depending on what you're trying to achieve.